# How to properly add Custom View in toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am adding a custom view in toolbar but it is not using full toolbar width it gives space from left side.

code snippet

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

getting view from this code snippet

Can anyone please tell me Why it is not using full width of toolbar?

[image]

Comment: that is the default padding of toolbar

Comment: If I want to remove it than What I need to do?

Comment: create it using relative layout

Comment: I had done with both Layout but its not working

Comment: @Ronitkadwane have you tried setting the four attributes I suggested in my answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Add these 4 attributes in your toolbar it should help you override that effect**.

```
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"  app:contentInsetLeft="0dp" app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Do let me know if this was of any help.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is only happens on Android version Lollipop and above. To remove the padding, you can set the content inset to 0dp

Add these to your toolbar

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

It has been reported as an issue here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213826